# Message Parameter conditions "rejection" not met for actual request parameters: reason={}

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, httprequest, thymeleaf

I have a problem with my Thymeleaf template and/or my Controller.

The template looks like this:

```
<div align="left">
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/rejection/{invoiceId}(invoiceId=${invoiceId})}" th:object="${rejection}" method="post">
        <ul class="form-style-1">
            <li>
                <label>Powód odrzucenia:<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{reason}" id="reason" required>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="submit" value="Wyślij powód odrzucenia protokołu"/>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here are the controller methods:

```
@GetMapping(params = "invoiceId", path = "/reject")
public String reject(@RequestParam("invoiceId") String invoiceId, @CurrentUser Contractor contractor, Model model) {
    InvoiceData invoiceData = invoiceDataRepository.findById(invoiceId).get();
    invoiceData.setStatus(StatusEnum.REJECTED.toString());
    invoiceDataRepository.save(invoiceData);
    Rejection rejection = new Rejection(invoiceId, null);
    model.addAttribute("contractor", contractor);
    model.addAttribute("rejection", rejection);
    return "reject";
}

@PostMapping(params = "rejection", path = "/rejection")
public String rejection(@RequestParam("rejection") Rejection rejection, @CurrentUser Contractor contractor, Model model) {
    InvoiceData invoiceData = invoiceDataRepository.findById(rejection.getInvoiceId()).get();
    model.addAttribute("contractor", contractor);
    model.addAttribute("rejection", rejection);
    emailService.sendRejectionMessage(contractor.getEmail(), invoiceData, rejection.getReason());
    logger.info("Invoice number "+ invoiceData.getInvoiceNumber() +" with ID " + invoiceData.getId() + " rejected for Contractor with ID " + contractor.getId());
    return "index";
}
```

When I am trying to send the data from the reject template I get an error:

```
2019-06-12 15:04:13.451  WARN 23678 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException: Parameter conditions "rejection" not met for actual request parameters: reason={some text here}]
```

Here is the Rejection class:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Rejection {

    private String invoiceId;
    private String reason;

}
```

What am I doing wrong? The request param is an `Rejection` object, not just the `Rejection` field `reason`...

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're seeing that error is because you have `params = "rejection"` in your `@PostMapping`.  It's expecting a parameter with the name `rejection` and you haven't supplied any.  Just remove that, unless you have a specific reason for having it.